# Fetch pdf from S3 bucket and display in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, amazon-s3

How can I fetch and display Fetch pdf from S3 bucket and display in bootstrap modal,

I have tried like below

```
 //href to open modal
 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#InvoiceModal">Filename</a>



//bootstrap modal

<div id="InvoiceModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Invoice</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            //here i am trying to fecth pdf file
            <embed src="<?php echo base_url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/j2wmsp/production/invoice_reports/2018-10-05%2011:58:38-Invoice6(%20Venkata%20Sameer%20Kota-Sep%202018).pdf'); ?>"
                           frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code display empty modal, How can I display PDF file,

Thanks.

Comment: As your question hasn't received a lot of attentention so far, I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally some errors and a better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). **Please edit your post accordingly**, that way you can get answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the bootstrapmodel. The problem is in amazons3 bucket.
You need to change the Content-Type and Content-Disposition.

```
Content-Type: application/pdf;
Content-Disposition: inline;
```

Using the AWS S3 console, find the file and using the context menu (right click) select Properties then it's under Metadata.